# what's the difference between two codes

Tags: java, import, universe

I'm trying to submit the second code on spoj but it gives wrong answer but the first one is accepted although i think that the logic of the two codes are the same.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        java.io.BufferedReader r = new java.io.BufferedReader(
                new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s;
        while (!(s = r.readLine()).startsWith("42"))
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if (n != 42) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to execute both snippets using `42xyz` as input string

Comment: The difference between the 2 codes is that the second code attempts to convert String into a number which may cause number format exception if the string is not numeric

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop in your second code. Try your code using the following input data:

```
1
2
88
42
99
```

Your second code is going to process only first line on the input (i.e. `1`). Here is the working example of **your** code: http://ideone.com/Qr1q3N

You can, for example, introduce a loop in the following way:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n;
        while ((n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())) != 42) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see this code in action: http://ideone.com/z8H4fP